# Download files from HTML page subfolders

Tags: c#, html, api, html-agility-pack

https://marketplace.spp.org/pages/tcr-auction-historical-results

Is there a way the list of folders and the csv files they point to can be extracted through the api post call instead of **scraping** html data -> navigating to the folder location -> **scraping** html again to get the list of files and downloading them?

Comment: I don't think so, unless they have some type of XML sitemap some where that would allow you to get a list of files with a single call.

Comment: yeah I was thinking I might have to go the htmlagility pack route to parse the specific elements from the html